# Simplifying Gamma Function

Tags: probability, statistics

The questons asked to find the variance of T where T = z/sqrt(y/v) where z is the standard normal distribution and y is the chi-squared divided by degree of freedom.
I found the raw moment of a chi-squared with v degree of freedom and ended up with 
$$2^a \frac{\Gamma(\frac{v}{2} +a ) }{\Gamma(\frac{v}{2})}$$
When negative -1 is plugged in for a it is suppose to ssimply out to $\frac{1}{2(v/2-1)}$

I'm having trouble getting it into that form.

Comment: You have $z\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$ for all $z$. Set $z = \frac{v}{2}-1$.

Comment: So it should be $$((v/2)-1) \frac{\Gamma(\frac{v}{2} -1 +1 ) }{\Gamma(\frac{v}{2})}$$
So the gammas cancel out and you end up with $\frac{\frac{v}{2}-1}{2}$ But how does that simply to $\frac{1}{2(v/2-1)}$

Comment: No, $\frac{v}{2} = z+1$, so $\Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right) =\;?$